# Automatically Step Through List of Numbers in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a long list of numbers (about 200) and would like to do the following in Beamer:

1. Display the first number.
2. Pause for one second.
3. Erase the first number.
4. Display the second number.

...and so on for the entire list. My current hack is the following:

```
\begin{frame}
\foreach \n in {0, 1, 2, 3}{
\n \\
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\pause
{\color{white} \n}\\
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
}
\end{frame}
```

This leaves an undesirable artifact from the white numbers and does not advance automatically. What is a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use transitions (Acrobat Reader required); see Section **14.3 Slide Transitions** of the `beamer` manual for further details and effects:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\foreach \n [count=\i] in {0, 1, 2, 3}
{
\transduration<1->{1}
\only<\i>{\n}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```